# Should I use salt pellets for my new Clark water softener?

Tags: water, water-softener

I have a new Clark water softener. The technician recommended using Sure Soft with extra coarse. I have a few bags of Diamond Crystal salt pellets that I bought from Costco for my old water softener.

**My question is:** Should I continue using Diamond Crystal Salt Pellets, or should I buy the Sure Soft Extra Coarse, as the technician recommended? Can I put the Diamon Crystal Salt Pellets into the remaining of Sure Soft with Extra Coarse in the salt tank? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Salt is salt, pretty much. If you find trouble with a particular brand/type/size bridging excessively, it might be worth trying something else. Otherwise, it makes no difference to the operation of the softener.

Not packing the salt tank right to the tippy-top helps to reduce bridging issues, in my experience, brand and type agnostic.

**Bridging** being the condition where the salt cements itself into a structure that prevents salt falling into the water, because a crusty stuck-together dome of salt has formed under the loose salt on top. That can be broken up, but you have to notice it and then break it up. By which point you may have had a few weak regenerations...